# Add quotes around a value using sed

Tags: sed

I created file called Test1.txt and I add a line.

The file look like this,

```
TEST = admin
```

Now I want to add double quotes for TEST="admin".

How to add double quotes using sed command?

I want Test1.txt look like this below

```
TEST = "admin"
```

Comment: How did a perfectly fine question end-up receiving that many downvotes?

Answer (score 7):

```
sed 's/\(=[[:blank:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1"\2"/'
```

Would add quotes around what's on the right of the first occurrence of an equal sign and the blanks if any that follow it.

Comment: In `sed`, printable whitespace can be matched with `\s` which is slighlty more practical.

Comment: @orion, that's only in GNU `sed`, and `\s` also includes vertical space characters which you don't want here (though it's unlikely to harm). `[:blank:]` is POSIX and portable.

Comment: Sorry. As a GNU+linux user, I always silently assume GNU without thinking. It probably works for most people here.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `sed` and assuming `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment:

```
sed 's/\badmin\b/"admin"/' -i filename
```

where -i means "inplace". The `\b` is there for safety (to only match the whole word, but not "administrator").

Comment: This only works for the one hard coded value in the question. Presumably if they were only trying to fix one instance they could either fix it at the source or do virtually any other search and replace function. This does not provide a generic solution that is useful for anybody except _maybe_ the original poster.